# Pseudo class :before selectors in specific <li> element

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I need to add different text for each item in an unordered list. The ul have a class name but I can't modify the li elements using :before pseudo class. As I have other lists I really need to specify the elements in each ul/li combo. Am I missing something?

```css
    ul.links li:nth-child(1) a:before {
      content: "++";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }

    ul.links li:nth-child(2) a:before{
      content: "**";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }
    
   ul.links li:nth-child(3) a:before{
      content: "##";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="link">
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `ul` class is `link` and your css selector is `.links`.

Comment: <facepalm> that was it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your class name to be the same in your CSS and HTML

```css
    ul.link li:nth-child(1) a:before {
      content: "++";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }

    ul.link li:nth-child(2) a:before{
      content: "**";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }
    
   ul.link li:nth-child(3) a:before{
      content: "##";
      padding-right: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="link">
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Linked Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

since you're styling everything inside the unordered list you could simply write this code:

```
.link>*:before {
  content: /*your content here*/;
}
```

or maybe the question is not clear enough

Comment: HI, thanks for your comment. I changed it to better reflect the question --I really need to change each li element under a specific ul. I have another list with pseudo classes so in thsi case I need to apply the :before to the items in this particular <ul>